# set python path in MSYS2

Tags: python, msys2

I've installed python 3 under MSYS2 using this command:

```
 pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-python
```

but when I run `python --version` I get:

```
 python: command not found
```

Tried to setup the PATH with export `PATH="D:/MSYS2/mingw64/bin:$PATH"` and it works but I have to run it each time I close the console.
Any suggestions on how to set the PATH permanently under MSYS2?

Thank you!

Comment: I don't have one so far, I'm trying to run verilator, and I get this message: "configure: error: Cannot find "python3" in your PATH, please install it". I'm following these steps https://gist.github.com/sgherbst/036456f807dc8aa84ffb2493d1536afd

Comment: You may have to read up a lot on the documentation: [PATH](https://www.msys2.org/wiki/MSYS2-introduction/#path) [terminals](https://www.msys2.org/docs/terminals/) [Environments](https://www.msys2.org/docs/environments/) [Launchers](https://www.msys2.org/wiki/Launchers/) and so on. It seems a little complicated for the uninitiated :(

Comment: You might like to try just installing Git-for-Windows which is based on msys2 ... then you will have their gitbash console which is basically set up for regular use like a normal bash terminal in linux (so to speak) and will work with a normal .bashrc in your home folder so you can add your export commands to update the path to your .bashrc  -  I assume you have msys2 "for free" that way ... then you could just install verilator in your gitbash terminal and start using it ... ?